# Microsoft outlook API

Tags: outlook, outlook-api

Anyone knows if outlook mail API have a way to retrieve the user mail signature, to use on mail.send?

I already saw the documentation regarding to mail, contacts, settings etc but didn't found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no method or property in the Outlook Object Model to read signatures.  The signatures are actually stored as files - just read them from the \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures folder.  There will be three file variations for each signature, one for text, RTF and HTML.